Allocate extra WASM memory to generate large chainspecs
In some cases, generating a chainspec may overload the memory allocated by the WASM blob which results in an Requested allocation size is too large error:
❯ staking-node build-spec --disable-default-bootnode > chain-specs/staking-max.spec --raw
2024-08-20 14:58:04 Building chain spec
2024-08-20 14:58:07 going to fail due to allocating 54354570
Error: Service(Other("wasm call error Requested allocation size is too large"))

How to tweak the WASM allocated memory to allow for generating specs that require more than the default 32 MiB allocated memory?


Note: this is a hack and not a clean solution. With this hack, you can generate the new chainspec and revert the changes made.


Change the MAX_POSSIBLE_ALLOCATION to a value large enough to cover the required allocating memory.

// in substrate/primitives/core/src/lib.rs

// increase max possible allocation to 64MiB
pub const MAX_POSSIBLE_ALLOCATION: u32 = 67_108_864; // 2^26 bytes, 64 MiB


Increase the number or orders in the client's allocator code:

// in substrate/client/allocator/src/freeing_bump.rs

// increase the number or binary "orders" to accumulate the `MAX_POSSIBLE_ALLOCATION` 
const N_ORDERS: usize = 26;


Add the initial-memory and max-memory clink arguments to the node's build script to cover the 64MiB memory allocation.

// in node/build.rs

#[cfg(feature = "std")]
fn main() {
  substrate_wasm_builder::WasmBuilder::init_with_defaults()
    .append_to_rust_flags("-Clink-args=--initial-memory=67108864")
    .append_to_rust_flags("-Clink-args=--max-memory=67108864")
    .build();
}

The chainspec generation should work now, provided that the allocated memory required fits within 64MiB.

This is more a hack and not a solution. Can you not split up the field that contains the data that is too big?

@bkchr I added a note stating this is a hack and not a clean solution. In any case, I think it may be useful to generate large chainspecs that can be used by nodes without any changes. In any case, yes, another option would be to drop the (large) vec of new accounts being generated in the chainspec (the vec of accounts is used later on in another step of the chainspec generation, but there are ways to avoid the memory allocation issues).
